# Migrate one postgresql table to another

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table like this:

```
id
task_title
task_desc
creation_date
```

Now I want to migrate it to another table like this

```
id
task_title
task_desc
creation_date
old_task_id
```

So what is the best way to make this happen? I think about a bash script to take the entries from the first and instert them in the new one but I don't know how to write the old id field entries to the old_task_id filed in the new one.

### Edit

Then I have a third table like this:

```
id
filename
file_path
task_id
```

Now when I make the migration in this table must the field task_id be updated. Is there a good way for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT` statements like so:

```
INSERT INTO new_table (task_title, task_desk, creation_date, old_task_id) VALUES (SELECT task_title, task_desc, creation_date, id FROM old_table);
```

Comment: Ok, but what is with the old_task_id field

Comment: Oh, I get it--updated my answer (assuming your new table's id is auto-generated)

Comment: Now I see I have a database with some files that has a filed task_id how can I now take from the `new_table` the id and update it in the `table_files` task_id what actually based on the old_task_id?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused--are you asking about another table now?  Could you perhaps update your original post with the full details so that it's easier for future readers to follow?

Comment: l did see the first post